obtaining both manual and drop-down choices back to SP List
Good evening.  I am new to Power Apps and am trying a Custom Form for a SP List.  I have a column that is a drop down, multi-select choices.  It is also a mandatory field and is to allow multiple selections.  At the present, I can EITHER obtain a "custom" (manual) choice back to the SP List OR the drop-down item(s), but not BOTH.
My formula in the update field is:
If(!IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems),DataCardValue2.SelectedItems, If(!IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SearchText),{Value: DataCardValue2.SearchText}, Blank()))
How can I get BOTH values of the manual choice AND the drop-down item(s)?

Try this formula:
If(
    !IsBlank(DataCardValue5.SelectedItems),
    If(
        IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SearchText),
        DataCardValue2.SelectedItems,
        Ungroup(
            Table(
                {MyTables: Ungroup(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems,Value)},
                {MyTables: Table({Value: DataCardValue2.SearchText})}
            ),
            MyTables
        )
    ),
    If(
        !IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SearchText),
        {Value: DataCardValue2.SearchText},
        {Value: Blank()}
    )
)

